# Searching for objects matching a particular type

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I've got an `NSViewController` extension that iterates through all its descendant child view controllers looking for the first view controller that passes a particular test (specified by a user-defined block):

```
extension NSViewController {

    func descendantViewControllerPassingTest(test: (viewController: NSViewController) -> Bool) -> NSViewController? {
        var retval: NSViewController?
        for childViewController in childViewControllers {
            if test(viewController: childViewController) {
                retval = childViewController
            } else if let descendantViewController = viewController.descendantViewControllerPassingTest(test)  {
                retval = descendantViewController
            }
            if retval != nil { break }
        }
        return retval
    }
}
```

Ninety-nine percent of the time my tests consist of a simple type-check...

```
contentViewController.descendantViewControllerPassingTest {$0 is OutlineViewController}
```

...so I'd like to create a short convenience extension that does this:

```
extension NSViewController {
    func descendantViewControllerMatchingType(type: WHAT_HERE?) {
        return descendantViewControllerPassingTest({ $0 is WHAT_HERE? })
    }
}
```

But I can't work out what `type` my parameter *type* should be. I've tried `AnyClass` and `AnyObject` but the compiler informs me that these aren't types:

[image]

Comment: I have little experience with generics, but I think understanding generics is the right direction. I guess you could use a generic type. But as I said, I don't have enough experience to be of more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

[Closures](http://fuckingswiftblocksyntax.com/) is what I'd use. Pass in your object to the closure with a return type of BOOL. Use the closure to match your descendant recursively.